# Number of bit operations required for encryption in a Block cipher

Tags: symmetric, complexity

I want to find out how many bit operations are performed for encryption in AES-128 with messages size $128$ bits.

For public key encryptions such as RSA and ElGamal, I know that number of bit operations required are $O(n^3)$ if the key considered has $n$ bits.

Are these equal to $O(1)$?

Comment: This question has been asked before. No, we don't use Big-Oh for symmetric ciphers, And that really depends on the implementation, use of a pre-computed table or not, etc. The only article that really counted is [TOA et. al](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-319-19962-7_3)  They went on this to show that their attack better than the brute-force.

Comment: And, for the RSA, Why it is $O(n^3)$?

Comment: RSA involves modular exponentiation. So, if we use square and multiply algorithm, then it is so. It can further be optimized.

Comment: It is $\mathcal{O}(3\cdot n^2)$ at most whem $e=3$

Comment: But e is not 3, in general. What if I want to send a same messages to more than 3 entities?